# How to handle overlapping button OnTouch Event in Android

Tags: android, button, ontouchlistener

I'm working on an android application which have multiple overlapping buttons and i want to perform some action on the touch event of each button(I'm adding these buttons through java code not XML).
[Overlapping buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9EEu.png)

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchListener(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    if(MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
       //action to perform
    }
    return true;
}
```

what i want to do is ,as i touch Button 1 and move towards Button 2 and Button 3 respectively without leaving the screen and when my finger comes overs the button 2 then button 2 touch Actions should perform and code should stop executing Button 1 actions.

Currently what happening is, as i touch button 1 and comes over button 2 still code is executing button 1 actions ,and once i leave the screen and touch button 2 or Button 3 actions associated with them starts executing.
i want to perform actions associated with buttons as i touch any button and move over any other button so code should identify the button i'm touching and perform actions associated to that button only.
Please reply if any confusion...

Answer (score 0):

You have to listen and intercept touch events that you are interested in from parent `ViewGroup`. See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html) for more details on that.

From documentation of [ViewGroup#onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)):

> Implement this method to intercept all touch screen motion events. This allows you to watch events as they are dispatched to your children, and take ownership of the current gesture at any point.

Comment: how to implement this method with Existing RelativeLayout in android XML  ?
If you can give any example through code that would be very helpful .

Comment: still problem is not solved .. Let me explain i can set the return false from onTouch of view to handle touch event by previous childs ,
in my Diagram :- if i touch button 3 then it will dispatch event to previous child(button 2 and then button 1) but what i want that if i touch button 1 and then move to button 2 (which is top child than button 1) it will not dispatch event to button 2 or button 3.